# After formatting Month part of the datetime changes to "00"

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a `DateTime` object in the format

```
StartDate = 19-03-2014 00:00:00
```

And I am trying to convert it to `03/19/2014`. Here is my code to do that

```
<input type="text"  value="<%#Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("StartDate")).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") %>"/>
```

But this returns a string

```
00-19-2014
```

I can't understand why this happens, Can any one point out what is going wrong here?

Comment: DateTime objects have no format. What is the type of StartDate?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos its DateTime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`mm` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#mmSpecifier) is for minutes. It prints `00` because your minutes of `StartDate` is `00`.

Use [`MM` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier) instead which is for months from `01` to `12`.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("StartDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

For more information, take a look at;

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

`DateTime` has no implicit format, it is just a `DateTime` value. You can format it as `string`.

As additional, [`"/"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning of *"replace me with the current culture's date separator"*

Looks like your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`DateSeperator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `-` and `/` replace itself to it.

If you really want your output with `/` seperator, you can use a culture which has `/` `DateSeperator` (like [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) as a second parameter in your `ToString` method like;

```
Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("StartDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

or you can escape it no matter which culture you use like;

```
Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("StartDate")).ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy")
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `\/` works. `/` is not a special character so adding `\\` in front of it will not escape it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are right. I made it as a _verbatim string literal_.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `MM` for months. `mm` is for minutes

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MM_Specifier):

> The "MM" custom format specifier represents the month as a number from
>   01 through 12 (or from 1 through 13 for calendars that have 13
>   months). A single-digit month is formatted with a leading zero.

Try this:

```
<input type="text"  value="<%#Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("StartDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

DateTime objects have no format. Formats apply *only* when converting them from/to strings.

If `StartDate` is an actual DateTime object, there is no reason to convert it to text and back, a simple ToString will do:

```
DateTime StartDate=new DateTime(2014,3,19);
var usStyle=StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

If `StartDate` is a string, `Convert.ToDateTime`, `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` should be used to create a DateTime object first.

In this case, you should ensure that the string has the format expected by your statement. `Convert.ToDateTime` or `DateTime.Parse` without a format specifier will only work if the string is already formatted in the thread's culture.

A common gotcha in some cultures is that `/` is actually the date separator. If this different than `\` (eg. '-') the result will be in the form `03-19-2014`.

ToString() or String.Format will treat `/` as a literal if it's surrounded by `'` or `"`, eg:

```
var usStyle=StartDate.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy");
```

A better option, is to specify the actual culture you want to use. In this case, it sounds like you want to use the US culture:

```
var usCulture=CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
var usStyle=StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy",usCulture);
```

This way you keep your format string clean and make explicit what you are trying to achieve.

Finally, you may prefer to set the Culture used for your entire page or your entire application, as described in "[How To: Set the Culture and UI Culture in ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)".

You can set the culture for the entire application by setting the following in `web.config`:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />
```

You can set the culture for specific pages by adding this tag in the page header:

```
<%@ Page UICulture="en" Culture="en-US" %>
```

These settings affect all culture-specific processing so you should make sure they are appropriate for your case

Comment: Everything worked fine excepts still string displays in the format MM-dd-yyyy. Can you please explain how i could change it to MM/dd/yyyy ?

Comment: This means that your locale's date separator is `-` instead of  the `/` used in most cultures. `/` in a date format string is replaced by the locale's date separator. You need to force ToString to tread `\` as a literal by surrounding it with `'`. Check the updated answer